# Open File Which is already open in window explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I am trying to open a file using `OpenFileDialog`.

```
if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "" && resultSaveDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            openFileDialog1.OpenFile(); // Throw Exception Here
            txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;                
        }
```

But if file is already opened in window explored it throws me following exception

> The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\Projects\CDR_RAW_FILES\GroupData\8859511378.xls' because it is
>   being used by another process.

Is it possible to open the file Using `OpenFileDialog` even if file has already opened in window Explorer.

Comment: (Clone / Copy) & Open

Comment: why do you want to open the File...? to get any data...? or just read filename...?

Comment: @Pandian Just to get the Open File name and path

Comment: @RajeevKumar you just need the filename and its path then try the Solution i have added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, If you just need the Selected File name and its path, Then try like below, It will help you...

```
if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "" && resultSaveDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
 string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
 txtFileName.Text = filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in some circumstances:
First possibillity: The other program does not lock the file (e.g. only allows itself to modify the file), than you can open it without problems.
Second possibillity: Your program does not need to WRITE to the file but only needs to read it you can open it in read-only mode.
I am not realls familiar with Winforms, but your Openfiledialog.OPenfile method seems to open the file in a "read and write" mode - so the second possibillity is out of the window.
However, if you are willing to use the Classes under My.Computer  you can simply open the file with methods like readalltext (depending on your problems) which should accept read only overloads.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile(v=vs.110).aspx As on their MSDN page, the OpenFile() Method opens in read-only mode by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add you can get a filename before opening a file using the OpenFile() Method. Use the properties [SafeFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx) or [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) to get it.

```
if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "" && 
    resultSaveDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;                
    }
```

Although I haven't tested this, [SafeFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx) should work for what you need *if all you need is the filename and no path*_.

If you need the full path to your file and not just the filename and extension then use the [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) property:

```
if (openFileDialog1.FileName != "" && 
    resultSaveDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;                
    }
```

The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").