# Tkinter FileDialog.askopenfilename failing on already open files

Tags: python, tkinter

I can not find a way using the the Tkinter `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` / `Open()` method to get a file name of an already opened file. At least on Windows 7 anyway.

Simply need to return the filename selected, but when I select an 'opened' file I get the `"This file is in use"` popup. Any searches for getting filenames seems to always point back to using `FileDialog`.

There seems to be the same question but using c# here:
[Open File Which is already open in window explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516341/open-file-which-is-already-open-in-window-explorer)

Are there any ways not listed that can be used to arrive at this? A file selection popup that doesn't fail on already opened files on Windows 7?

Python 2.7.11
Windows 7_64

Selection dialog:

```
opts = {}
opts['title'] = 'Select file.'

filename  = tkFileDialog.Open(**opts).show()
```

or

```
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**opts)
```

Which are the same as `askopenfilename` calls `Open().show()` which in turn is calling `command = "tk_getOpenFile"`.

Searching `tk_getOpenFile` shows nothing to override this behavior.

Any pointers here would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

So as to not reiterate everything that's been gone over here's the break down of the Tkinter 8.5 FileDialog.

```
def askopenfile(mode = "r", **options):
    "Ask for a filename to open, and returned the opened file"

    filename = Open(**options).show()
    if filename:
        return open(filename, mode)
    return None

def askopenfilename(**options):
    "Ask for a filename to open"

    return Open(**options).show()
```

Both call the Open class but askopenfile follows up with an open(file), here:

```
class Open(_Dialog):
    "Ask for a filename to open"

    command = "tk_getOpenFile"

    def _fixresult(self, widget, result):
        if isinstance(result, tuple):
            # multiple results:
            result = tuple([getattr(r, "string", r) for r in result])
            if result:
                import os
                path, file = os.path.split(result[0])
                self.options["initialdir"] = path
                # don't set initialfile or filename, as we have multiple of these
            return result
        if not widget.tk.wantobjects() and "multiple" in self.options:
            # Need to split result explicitly
            return self._fixresult(widget, widget.tk.splitlist(result))
        return _Dialog._fixresult(self, widget, result)
```

UPDATE2(answerish):

Seems the windows trc/tk tk_getOpenFile ultimately calls

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
```

which apparently can not, at times, return a filename if the file is in use.
Yet to find the reason why but regardless.

In my case, needing to reference a running QuickBooks file, it will not work using askopenfilename().

Again the link above references someone having the same issue but using c# .

Comment: Unable to reproduce; ``askopenfilename()`` produced no error when selecting a file that was open within Python.  I imagine that many things that I might want to do with that selected file might produce a "file in use" error, but that's hardly the fault of the file selector.

Comment: It is not a file opened twice by the same process. There are some accounting softwares out in the wild that run pointed to a single file. API access requires pointing to the same file. This all works perfectly. Simply wanted a UI way to gather the path vs tabbing in terminal.

Comment: Ok, tried again with a file open for write in another process.  ``askopenfilename()`` still produced no error for me.

Comment: The file selection fails on this file. Text files seem to work no problem. I don't need to open it, no need in reading the file. Just trying to get the path but apparently tk_getOpenFile fails on this file as it must be doing more than collecting a path, perhaps verifying the file? There is a reference about this in the c# link provided.